# Set style to textinputlayout inside alertdialog

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I'm trying to set the material.io `outlinedbox` style to my `textinputlayout` inside an `alertdialog`, but anything I try, the style returns to the alert dialog default. Is there  any way to set different styles to the `alertdialog` and to the `textinputlayout`?

I tried:

1. Setting the style directly to the `textinputlayout`:

```
var alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
alertDialog.setTitle("Crear aula")

var editText = AlertDialogEditText(this)
editText.style(R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox)
var textInputEditText = TextInputEditText(this)

editText.addView(textInputEditText)

alertDialog.setView(editText)

alertDialog.create().show()
```

2. Setting different contexts to the `alertdialog` and to the `textinputlayout`:

```
var alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
alertDialog.setTitle("Crear aula")

var editText = AlertDialogEditText(baseContext)
editText.style(R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox)
var textInputEditText = TextInputEditText(baseContext)

editText.addView(textInputEditText)

alertDialog.setView(editText)

alertDialog.create().show()
```

Whatever I try, I still get the default `textinputlayout` style.

Any ideas?